# PowerShell grouping multiple properties

Tags: powershell, grouping

I'm trying to figure out how to achieve the following using PowerShell.

I have a list of servers with the following headers: Server, Site, Domain

I want to create multiple sets of servers grouped according to the site and domain. But I'd like to have only 1 server per site per domain in a set.

Each domain may have multiple sites. So each set would potentially contain a single server from each site for each domain. the next set would be the same and so forth.

The idea is to then do some work against the set of servers.

Example:

```
Server1.domain1.com,Site1,Domain1 
Server2.domain1.com,Site1,Domain1
Server3.domain1.com,Site2,Domain1   
Server1.domain2.com,Site1,Domain2
Server2.domain2.com,Site2,Domain2
Server3.domain2.com,Site3,Domain2
Server1.domain3.com,Site1,Domain3
Server2.domain3.com,Site2,Domain3
Server3.domain3.com,Site3,Domain3
```

The sets would be:

```
Set1: Server1.domain1.com,Server3.domain1.com,Server1.domain2.com,Server1.domain3.com,Server3.domain2.com

Set2: Server2.domain1.com,Server2.domain2.com,Server2.domain3.com

Set3: Server3.domain3.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, got it :-)

```
$result = @()
$i = 0 

while(($serverlist|measure-object).count -gt 0)
{
    $templist = $serverlist|group-object Site,forest|%{$_.Group|select -first 1}|select -ExpandProperty Server
    $serverlist=$serverlist|?{$templist -notcontains $_.server}
    $tempObj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{"Set" = $i; "Servers"=$templist}
    $result+=$tempObj
    $i++
}
```